# JPA: How to get results by compromised where-clause

Tags: jpa, where-clause

I have a table with 30 columns.

I fill the object within my java code. Now I want to look up in my database, if the row is already inserted. I can do this primitive like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE table.name=object.name 
  AND table.street=object.street 
  AND ... 
  AND ... 
  AND ...
```

I think you get it. It works, but in my opinion this is not the best solution.

Is there any kind of a generic solution (eg: I do not need to change the code, if the table changes), where I can give the where-clause my object and it can match itself? Also the where-clause is not that massive.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that comes to mind is the Spring Data JPA [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html).

You can isolate the where clauses in an instance for a particular entity.

Afterwards, you just pass it to any of the `@Repository` methods:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>,
      JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

Then in your service:

```
  @Autowired
  private UrerRepository repo;

  public void findMatching() {
      List<User> users = repo.findAll(new MyUserSpecification());
```

Then, whenever db changes you simply alter one place, which is the Specification implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the solution I wanted to hear.

Comment: Are you actually even using JPA?

Comment: Spring Data JPA

Comment: Yes, i use JPA with Hibernate